# Page change monitor for Safari

Tags: ios-simulator

I'm looking for an app or add on to use with my ipad that notifies me when a webpage changes. Google chrome has add on for such but I can't find anything for Safari/ipad. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but have found an app called iChanged lite that appears to do the job but i am in the process of dowloading it.
Good Luck

Comment: This does not answer the question.